# Android Best Practice for Displaying Profile of a User

Tags: php, android, mysql, http

I'm working on my first Android app to learn the basics. Right now I have set up the login and register activities by connecting to a MySQL db using Volley to call PHP scripts. In other words, I have a login.php and register.php that interact with my db.

The thing I am currently trying to figure out is the best way I can display a user's profile once they log in. I have set up the SharedPreferences to store the username and password of the currently logged in user. Once they log in or register they are sent to a Profile activity which for now will simply display their user details (email, username, password, birthday), but will later display their friends list and recent activities. Given that I am storing the username and password in SharedPreferences, I am planning on making a POST request to another PHP script called profile.php. This script will query for the record which matches the username and password parameters passed in and respond with that data in JSON format (of course after validations).

I intuitively feel that this would work, but I can't help but feel like it's not the best way to do it and that it's not secure. As I am new to Android and somewhat new to webdev related stuff, I was hoping some of you more experienced developers could recommend the best/industry-standard practice for achieving this kind of thing. That is, for example, if you sign in to your Facebook, Snapchat, Instagram accounts on your phone, how do all those apps display your profile efficiently?

Thanks!

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS